# Email templates in DNN

Tags: email, templates, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

is there any ability to create custom email templates in dnn 8, I didn't found anything in the official documentation related about this topic.
Thanks !

Comment: No. And if it were possible, when or where would you send these? But you can modify the existing ones by editing the correct value in one of the `resx` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emails that DNN sends out are templated via language resource (`.resx`) files, which you can edit through the Languages module under the Admin menu.  From that interface, you can edit the site's language, and then edit the `GlobalResources` file in the Global Resources section of the editor.  (In DNN 9, this interface is now under the *Languages* tab within *Site Settings*, and you click the *Translate* button for the site's language).

If you want to add arbitrary new emails that you send to groups, there is not a built-in mechanism for that.  There's an old "core" module, [Newsletters](https://github.com/DNNCommunity/Dnn.Newsletter), which can be used for that, or you can search on the [DNN Store](https://store.dnnsoftware.com) for a more full-featured module.  However, the typical recommendation is to export your user list to a service like Mail Chimp or Constant Contact, rather than sending emails directly through the DNN site.

Finally, if you're building a custom extension which needs to send email, you can use the [`Mail.SendEmail`](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/dnn-api/?topic=html/753096bb-ab26-82aa-73d0-24de9fb68324.htm) or [`Mail.SendMail`](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/dnn-api/?topic=html/17879199-7dd1-f6cf-0ed4-fa4eb4a7e9bf.htm) methods (`SendEmail` is more simple/streamlined, `SendMail` has more options).